# ADO.net is not closing TCP connections fast enough

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net, sqlconnection, sqlexception

I'm running a multi-threaded operation that fetches data from a SQL Server database using `SqlConnection` and `Parallel.ForEach()` and following is happening:

- I wrap `SqlConnection` in a `using` statement so that the connection is properly disposed.
- My process consistently throws an `SqlException` wrapped in an `AggregateException` after running successfully for some time ("A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server..")
- I  found that this happens right around 2^14 (16384) calls to the database (in total, across all threads).
- I fired up perfmon and I can see that that's also the number of TCP connections that are open right around the time that the exception is thrown ("Connections Established" counter).
- I'm certain that there's no connection leakage in my code - there are very few places where I am querying the database and they all properly dispose the connection (in fact, there is no other pattern I use for querying the database other than vanilla `using(...)`)
- I turned off the connection pool and the same behavior occurs.
- Oddly, if I delete an index in SQL Server that makes my queries fast, the operation completes successfully (albeit very slowly) - no exception is thrown.  I observe that # of Connections Established rises linearly to about 13K and then stabilizes for some time, and then there's some periods with a linear decline, all while the operation is running.
- My conclusion is that with the index established, .net is processing data more quickly than it can close out the connections and eventually hits some kind of OS or .NET socket max threshold.  Without the index, .NET is still maintaining too many connections, but it has the time to close enough of them down so that the max open sockets threshold is not hit.

I'm at a loss on how to instruct .NET to close-out those connections.  I thought that that happened auto-magically when the `SqlConnection` is disposed.

Comment: what's particularly bizarre is that when the connection pool is active using the default setting (100 connections), that ADO is fine with opening way more TCP connecitons - its as if the pooled connections are just getting abandoned?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with how the connection is opened.  I'm using this constructor

`public SqlConnection(string connectionString, SqlCredential credential)`

It seems that ADO creates a new connection pool, even when `connectionString` is the same and `credential` encapsulates the same credentials.  My guess is that  ADO somehow can't relate the credential to prior calls (maybe it would work if I was using the same credential object by using reference equality?  In my case, I create a new SqlCredential with each call).

Because of a new pool is created each time, the number of TCP connections balloons.  I think this also makes sense when the connection pool is turned off.  Likely some of the socket or TCP settings are kicking-in here (keep alives?) and the OS is keeping the connections open to respect those settings.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the connection objects are getting released back to the pool, the unmanaged resources might not be getting released until a garbage collection is performed. By slowing the commands (removing that index), you are giving the GC enough time to release the resources back to the OS.

If you aren't using Async command execution, you could try to cache connection objects at the thread level. The parallel operations would then just keep re-using the same open connections instead of grabbing new sockets and such.

I haven't done any testing with async operations in regards to prevent some resource overuse. I believe they will use IO completion ports to prevent blocking. And, you definitely wouldn't want two command objects in that state using the same connection object.

Comment: maybe a periodic call to GC.Collect() would be enough, and I could avoid the complexity of cacheing.

Comment: Calling `GC.Collect` followed by `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` doesn't seem to help.